# Make logged-in author user in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

This seems like a really simple requirement for a blogging app or CMS:

**How do you automatically make the logged-in user the author of a wagtail page?** For example, if I log in as "Bob" and type a post, the author should automatically be "Bob".

Normally I would simply write it into my Django views but since I'm using Wagtail I expect it to be in the main package. However, the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/index.html) don't mention it, and the [official demo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/blog/models.py) seems to imply that authors must be chosen from a dropdown select box, which means any author can pretend to be anyone else!

> We access the People object with an inline panel that references the
>       ParentalKey's related_name in BlogPeopleRelationship.

Is there a feature I've missed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user who created a page is available as the property `owner`:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.owner

This is used within Wagtail for permission checks (a user with 'add' but not 'edit' permission can edit pages that they have created themselves), but it can also be displayed on your site front-end as the page author if you so desire.